# Discord.js Tag Channel in Rich Embed

Tags: node.js, channel, discord.js

I'd like to tag the channel like here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1fxj.png

But when I use "message.channel" I get <#ID>

with  message.channel.send() "message.channel" works how it should.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to input <#ChannelID> into your embed

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle('Say hello in the following channel: <#CHANNELID>')
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [the following raised issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1519), discord doesn't support mentions or markdown in embed titles